# How to capture all the header and field information line by line in a txt file and store in a struct or array

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement, bufferedreader, talend

I have a text file that looks like the below with header and other field information(expression) listed as:

```
Sample.txt FILE:
Header
Name:Tom-Chady
Zip:92840.000
City:Atlanta

Column fields(expression):
RowData:000 000 000 000 ___ @@@ 000 000 000 000 ___ ___
RowData:000  ___ ___ ___
RowData: ___ 000 000 037 ___ ___ ___
```

I would want to store the header and expression values in a structure or something similar to a cell array data structure(matlab-Structure array struct([])) in JAVA

I believe java does not support structure,so what is the best way to store the information in a map_structure and perform validations and transformations against them

1.I want to transform the values from the original file Sample.txt file and convert and store the information in an Samplemodified.txt file
2.Conversions needed like:
a.In the header change from Zip:92840.000 to Zip:9284
b.In the expression data flip the values using switch case

```
 switch fieldvalue
   case '000'  % do nothing
    case '@@@'  % Reference die
        fieldvalue= '100';  
    case '___'  % do nothing
    otherwise
        fieldvalue= '001';
```

I have constructed the readline and switch case but my concern is how to create  a structure to do the validations and store the results in a new file and save it as samplemodified.txt

```
         int n = 200; // The line number
         int i=0;
         String line="";
   
 try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt)))
 {
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i++ < n) 
   {
        if (line.startsWith('RowData:')) 
            {
              line=line.replaceAll('@@@','015');
          } 
       } 
     }
```

But since this is a bufferedreader the value gets printed but not stored in the new file So i want to use  structure array using java to store the results in the new samplemodified.txt after transforming/manipulating the data as expected

Comment: what is the final purpose of your job ? do you have to provide a modified file ? store in a DB ? Your solution seems to be quite java-oriented, which is not the easiest way to work with Talend. Perhaps you should try to read your input file twice : one for the header, one for the body part, and join them after that.

Comment: Hi @Corentin yes i have to furnish a modified file with renamed title such as samplemodified.txt and also the contents in that being transformed as indicated above and place it in a folder.I am able to handle the superficial things like renaming the file and storing in a folder.The trickiest part is to validate and transform the contents inside the file and create a new version of the file to be stored?
I guess the best route would be to store the header & body in a structure array(concept in matlab) similar way in java probably object /arraylist?? and then do the manipulations inside?

Comment: @Corentin can you think of any better way to handle this?especially by using bufferedwriter to write the contents after modification onto a newly created file in java component.
I am able to do the transformations as expected however inorder to write the contents and transfer it wont work effectively

Comment: I think you should redefine the output structure, and use capacities of talend to transform your data (transformations in tMap for example). You could try to read your file twice :one for extracting the headers to a file, the second one to extract the body to a second file, then merge your files.  If you want to use cache to store temp data, look for the tHashInput/tHashOutput components. Most of the time, no need to write java code to transform data in Talend